# Use variable in condition Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Is there a way to concatenate strings with variables in a condition, without the use of inner tags such as `span` or other which could have `v-if`.

In the following example:

```
data() {
    return {
        useSnippet: true,
        name: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    }
}
```

The markup should display the data as follow:

```
<div>
    bunch of text
    {{useSnippet ? 'Hello {{name}}, your last name is {{lastName}}'}}
    bunch of text
</div>
```

This is of course returning an error.

The desired outcome would be:

```
bunch of textHello John, your last name is Doebunch of text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the turnery operator the syntax goes like this

condition?  :  but you have not used : so that is why I guess it is giving you an error

so you can do something like this
bunch of text
{{useSnippet ? `Hello ${name}, your last name is ${lastName}` : ''}}
bunch of text

Comment: No, this will not fix it, I had used this as well before, ```:null```

Comment: please check updated answer

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-bush-52gpq2?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Strange, I had used string literals before, and returned error, so stepped away from that. But this is the approach I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like following snippet:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      useSnippet: true,
      name: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    text() {
      return this.useSnippet ? `Hello ${this.name}, your last name is ${this.lastName}` : ''
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  bunch of text
  {{ text }}
  bunch of text
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this uses inner tags, ```span```, in this case, as mentioned in the question, I really want to avoid tags.

Comment: This works, but was more looking for inline, like answer provided below. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome mate, btw you should avoid logic in template.